# Buscar las coincidencias de un string en un Array

Tags: php, php5, php7

Tengo este código donde defino un array y luego hay un String , quiero buscar las coincidencias por cada posible valor del array , en este ejemplo me tendria que devolver 2 coincidencias en el string $nombreBuscar pero el print_r que realizo me devuelve un array vacio.

```
$arrayPacs = array('PAC1','PAC2','PAC3');
$nombreBuscar = 'esto es una prueba de PAC1 sobre la PAC1';

print_r(array_keys($arrayPacs,$nombreBuscar));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

Comment: ¿Cuál versión estás usando? Por favor ajusta las etiquetas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar esto:

```
$arrayPacs = array('PAC1','PAC2','PAC3');
$nombreBuscar = 'esto es una prueba de PAC1 sobre la PAC1';

$arr = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayPacs); $i++ )
{
    $text = "/".$arrayPacs[$i]."+/i"; //Expresion regular para buscar coincidencias
    preg_match_all($text, $nombreBuscar, $match);
    if(empty(!$match[0]))
    {
        $arr[$arrayPacs[$i]] = count($match[0]);//Array con numero de coincidencias
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($match[0]);//Se imprime el array que contiene las coincidencias
        echo "Num de coincidencias :".count($match[0]);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    else
    {
        $arr[$arrayPacs[$i]] = 0;
    }
}
print_r($arr);//Se imprime el array con el numero de coincidencias
```

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que quieres obtener algo así:

```
Array
(
    [PAC1] => 2
    [PAC2] => 0
    [PAC3] => 0
)
```

Podrías utilizar [array_map](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) para aplicar la misma función a cada posición de tu `$arrayPacs` y en esta función utilizar [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr-count.php) para contar el número de apariciones de cada posición del array en tu string:

```
$arrayPacs = array('PAC1','PAC2','PAC3');
$nombreBuscar = 'esto es una prueba de PAC1 sobre la PAC1';

$map = array_map(function($key) use ($nombreBuscar) {
    return substr_count($nombreBuscar, $key);
}, $arrayPacs);
$arrayPacs = array_combine($arrayPacs, $map); // Para mantener las keys de tu $arrayPacs
print_r($arrayPacs);
```

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Actualizo según comentario de @Sr1871, más correcto con **use**, pero apunto como funciona `use` vs `global` traducido de [**una respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741800/2550010) de SO en inglés:

```
$global_variable = 1;

$closure = function() use ($global_variable) {
    return $global_variable; 
};

$closure2 = function() {
    global $global_variable;
    return $global_variable;
};

$global_variable = 99;

echo $closure();    // Esto mostraría 1
echo $closure2();   // Esto mostraría 99
```

`use` toma el valor de `$global_variable` en el momento de la definición de la función (closure) mientras que `global` toma el valor actual de `$global_variable` en el momento de ejecución.

`global` hereda variables del ámbito global mientras que `use` las hereda de su ámbito local.

Si usásemos ...`use (&$global_variable)` obtendríamos el mismo resultado que con `global`.

Comment: el uso de global no es recomendado, bien podría quedar `function(key) use ($nombreBuscar){ ...`